# Are timeouts of requests waiting in the queue logged somewhere?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

We have had issues reported under heavy load that appear to indicate some requests waiting in CF's queue are being timed out and trying to get more info about this. The IIS log is not showing anything useful as far as I can tell. Is there standard log that would have these listed? If not, is there are place in CF or Tomcat config where logging can be enabled?

Comment: What do you see in the ColdFusion log files?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.cfguide.io/coldfusion-administrator/debugging-logging-log-files/) is one of many references to log files in ColdFusion.  Of course you have to know where they are and have permission to see them.

You can find out where the log files are by logging in to your server's ColdFusion Administrator page and looking to see what the path for log files is.

Then you can either map a drive to the server, or remote in, navigate to the location, and look at the appropriate file.  The errors might be in exception.log, application.log, or, looking at the screenshot in the link, coldfusion-error.log.